# Pass data between DHTMLX forms

Tags: dhtmlx

I'm trying to pass data between two forms in DHTMLX.

```
var formA, formB;
function jsFunction() {
   formA = new dhtmlXForm("formA_container");
   formA.loadStruct("formA.xml");
   formB = new dhtmlXForm("formB_container");
   formB.loadStruct("formB.xml");

   formA.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id) {
      if (id == "action1") {
         formB.setItemValue("lblValue", "0");
      }
   });
}
```

Still doens't work whether defining formA and formB are global or not.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, posting it in case anyone needs that.

Basically, create an object function to the form in order to get or set the values:

```
var formA, formB;
function jsFunction() {
   formA = new dhtmlXForm("formA_container");
   formA.loadStruct("formA.xml");
   formB = new dhtmlXForm("formB_container");
   formB.loadStruct("formB.xml");

   formB.setValueForObject = function (itemId, value) {
       formB.setItemValue(itemId, value);
   }

   formA.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(id) {
      if (id == "action1") {
         // formB.setItemValue("lblValue", "0");

         // This works !!
         formB.setValueForObject("lblValue", "0");
   }
});
}
```